# Want to practice DRY coding; can you take a look?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript right now and know I'm repeating myself with a function in this script.

The project I'm working on is a randomized fantasy character.

http://dapperdesign.me/charactercreator/

I have multiple functions in my .js file that have similar code blocks.

What I have is this:

```
//sample variable
const charClass = ['mage', 'warrior', 'rogue', 'paladin', 'wizard'];

//sample function
function getRandomClass() {
   var x = charClass[Math.floor(Math.random() * charClass.length)];
   return x;
}
```

What I would like is this (making up stuff from here on out):

```
function getRandom(anything){
var x = anything[Math.floor(Math.random() * anything.length)];
       return x;
}
```

So when I call it later I can use any attribute I've set up at the beginning of the program (i.e. class, hair, age, etc..).

Thanks guys!

Full program I have so far below:

```
//Establish some things
let gender = ['Male', 'Female'];
const firstMaleName = ['Win', 'Hakhad', 'Brirstirk', 'Olcerth', 'Benon',
'Lor', 'Meh', 'Fan', 'Tie', 'Arth', 'Stonnor', 'Razzik', 'Rungag', 'Maven', 'Corrin',
'Brother', 'Mason', 'Mannon', 'Brick', 'Atlas', 'Harry'];
const firstFemaleName = ['Naris','Cloud', 'Laflo', 'Wie', 'Rasal', 'Losho', 'Clara',
'Mara', 'Leia', 'Sunie', 'Elisabette', 'Mae', 'Willa', 'Gregina', 'Marry',
'Jessica', 'Sarah', 'Buff', 'Tate', 'Melody'];
const lastName = ['Dorilbes', 'Biv', 'Hia', 'Doomtail', 'Skullsher', 'Thuly', 'Gallagher',
'Riddon', 'Bont', 'Sercy', 'Lightfoot', 'Took', 'Baggins', 'Maple', 'Dickle', 'Slimer',
'Vinkman', 'Drake']
const hairColor = ['red', 'blonde', 'silver', 'white', 'black'];
const charClass = ['mage', 'warrior', 'rogue', 'paladin', 'wizard'];
const charMood = ['stoic', 'goofy', 'violent', 'complacent', 'silly', 'cautious', 'brave'];


//Decide gender
let myGender = gender[Math.floor(Math.random() * gender.length)];

function storyGender(){
  if (myGender === 'Male'){
    return 'man';
  } else {
    return 'woman';
  }
}


//Choose first name based on gender
function chooseName(){
if (myGender === 'Male'){
  var x = firstMaleName[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstMaleName.length)];
  return x;
} else { var y = firstFemaleName[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstFemaleName.length)];
return y;
}
}

//How old are you?
function age(){
let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
return x;
}

//Pick random last name (regardless of gender)
function getLastName() {
var x = lastName[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastName.length)];
return x;
}

//Pick random hair color
function getRandomHair() {
var x = hairColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * hairColor.length)];
return x;
}

//Pick a random class
function getRandomClass() {
var x = charClass[Math.floor(Math.random() * charClass.length)];
return x;
}

//Your disposition
function getMood() {
var x = charMood[Math.floor(Math.random() * charMood.length)];
return x;
}

//Test things
function testing(){
var msg = 'You are ' + chooseName() + ' ' + getLastName() + '. A ' + getMood() + ' ' + getRandomClass() + ' ' + 'who is ' + age() + ' years old, from a land far, far away.';
msg += ' Everyone notices your ' + getRandomHair() + ' hair as you stroll into the Inn. Your entrance captures the eyes of a shadowy figure in the room.';
msg += ' The shadow says, "Ah yes, just the ' + storyGender() + ' I was looking for..."';
return msg;
}
function reload() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: For example, do you mean to do getRandom(charClass), and have it return a char class, rather than having individual functions for each?

Instead of getRandomCharClass() etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh wow, had no clue codereview existed. Thanks!

Comment: @ocelot, yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

[Try looking into Switch Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp), they're effectively IF Statements that allow you to execute a code block if a certain condition is met.

In your example, you'd need a function that takes a parameter

```
function getRandom(attribute)
```

then, use the switch statement to check what the attribute is, and execute a code block based on that:

```
switch(attribute)
{
    case attribute == "class":
       var x = charClass[Math.floor(Math.random() * charClass.length)];
       return x;
       break;
}
```

and repeat for anything you need.